# Running PiHole from rPiW with safe shutdown

Tags: pi-zero, pi-zero-w, operating-systems, shutdown

I am new to Raspberry Pi, but I was looking to use one as a PiHole from the small Zero wireless series.

My thought was to run it connected to the router itself using the USB port from that to give it the power. When I switch my router off though, I don't want the power to cut from the Pi.

I looked into batteries, but then couldn't figure out how to have it shutdown if the battery was just continuing the running.

I wanted to see if this method: http://weworkweplay.com/play/rebooting-the-raspberry-pi-when-it-loses-wireless-connection-wifi/ was a good pathway but rather than reboot, shutdown?

With a battery connected, would this work?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Yes, you can shutdown using `shutdown`, just replace `-r` by  `-h`. How do you define a "good pathway"?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I've seen a lot of instructions about having an inverter, and wanted to know if the pinging method would still be suitable or if there was a better way than that link?